# Version of C# StringBuilder to allow for strings larger than 2 billion characters

Tags: c#, performance, strings, pagination

In C#, 64bit Windows, .NET 4.5 (or later), and enabling `gcAllowVeryLargeObjects` in the App.config file allows for objects larger than two gigabyte. That's cool, but unfortunately, the maximum number of elements that C# allows in an array is still [limited to about 2^31 = 2.15 billion](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcallowverylargeobjects-element). Testing confirmed this.

To overcome this, Microsoft [recommends in Option B](https://web.archive.org/web/20181119090643/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/joshwil/2005/08/10/bigarrayt-getting-around-the-2gb-array-size-limit/) creating the arrays natively. Problem is we need to use unsafe code, and as far as I know, unicode won't be supported, at least not easily.

So I ended up creating my own BigStringBuilder function in the end. It's a list where each list element (or page) is a char array (type `List<char[]>`).

Providing you're using 64 bit Windows, you can now easily surpass the 2 billion character element limit. I managed to test creating a giant string around 32 gigabytes large (needed to increase virtual memory in the OS first, otherwise I could only get around 7GB on my 8GB RAM PC). I'm sure it handles more than 32GB easily. In theory, it should be able to handle around 1,000,000,000 * 1,000,000,000 chars or one quintillion characters, which should be enough for anyone!

I also added some common functions to provide some functionality such as fileSave(), length(), substring(), replace(), etc. Like the StringBuilder, in-place character writing (mutability), and instant truncation are possible.

Speed-wise, some quick tests show that it's not significantly slower than a StringBuilder when appending (found it was 33% slower in one test). I got similar performance if I went for a 2D jagged char array (`char[][]`) instead of `List<char[]>`, but Lists are simpler to work with, so I stuck with that.

I'm looking for advice to potentially speed up performance, particularly for the append function, and to access or write faster via the indexer (`public char this[long n] {...}` )

```
// A simplified version specially for StackOverflow / Codereview
public class BigStringBuilder
{
    List<char[]> c = new List<char[]>();
    private int pagedepth;
    private long pagesize;
    private long mpagesize;         // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040646/faster-modulus-in-c-c
    private int currentPage = 0;
    private int currentPosInPage = 0;

    public BigStringBuilder(int pagedepth = 12) {   // pagesize is 2^pagedepth (since must be a power of 2 for a fast indexer)
        this.pagedepth = pagedepth;
        pagesize = (long)Math.Pow(2, pagedepth);
        mpagesize = pagesize - 1;
        c.Add(new char[pagesize]);
    }

    // Indexer for this class, so you can use convenient square bracket indexing to address char elements within the array!!
    public char this[long n]    {
        get { return c[(int)(n >> pagedepth)][n & mpagesize]; }
        set { c[(int)(n >> pagedepth)][n & mpagesize] = value; }
    }

    public string[] returnPagesForTestingPurposes() {
        string[] s = new string[currentPage + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < currentPage + 1; i++) s[i] = new string(c[i]);
        return s;
    }
    public void clear() {
        c = new List<char[]>();
        c.Add(new char[pagesize]);
        currentPage = 0;
        currentPosInPage = 0;
    }

    // See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373365/how-do-i-write-out-a-text-file-in-c-sharp-with-a-code-page-other-than-utf-8/373372
    public void fileSave(string path)   {
        StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path);
        for (int i = 0; i < currentPage; i++) sw.Write(new string(c[i]));
        sw.Write(new string(c[currentPage], 0, currentPosInPage));
        sw.Close();
    }

    public void fileOpen(string path)   {
        clear();
        StreamReader sw = new StreamReader(path);
        int len = 0;
        while ((len = sw.ReadBlock(c[currentPage], 0, (int)pagesize)) != 0){
            if (!sw.EndOfStream)    {
                currentPage++;
                if (currentPage == c.Count) c.Add(new char[pagesize]);
            }
            else    {
                currentPosInPage = len;
                break;
            }
        }
        sw.Close();
    }

    public long length()    {
        return (long)currentPage * (long)pagesize + (long)currentPosInPage;
    }

    public string ToString(long max = 2000000000)   {
        if (length() < max) return substring(0, length());
        else return substring(0, max);
    }

    public string substring(long x, long y) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (long n = x; n < y; n++) sb.Append(c[(int)(n >> pagedepth)][n & mpagesize]);    //8s
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public bool match(string find, long start = 0)  {
        //if (s.Length > length()) return false;
        for (int i = 0; i < find.Length; i++) if (i + start == find.Length || this[start + i] != find[i]) return false;
        return true;
    }
    public void replace(string s, long pos) {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)  {
            c[(int)(pos >> pagedepth)][pos & mpagesize] = s[i];
            pos++;
        }
    }

    // Simple implementation of an append() function. Testing shows this to be about
    // as fast or faster than the more sophisticated Append2() function further below
    // despite its simplicity:
    public void Append(string s)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            c[currentPage][currentPosInPage] = s[i];
            currentPosInPage++;
            if (currentPosInPage == pagesize)
            {
                currentPosInPage = 0;
                currentPage++;
                if (currentPage == c.Count) c.Add(new char[pagesize]);
            }
        }
    }

    // This method is a more sophisticated version of the Append() function above.
    // Surprisingly, in real-world testing, it doesn't seem to be any faster. 
    public void Append2(string s)
    {
        if (currentPosInPage + s.Length <= pagesize)
        {
            // append s entirely to current page
            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
            {
                c[currentPage][currentPosInPage] = s[i];
                currentPosInPage++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            int stringpos;
            int topup = (int)pagesize - currentPosInPage;
            // Finish off current page with substring of s
            for (int i = 0; i < topup; i++)
            {
                c[currentPage][currentPosInPage] = s[i];
                currentPosInPage++;
            }
            currentPage++;
            currentPosInPage = 0;
            stringpos = topup;
            int remainingPagesToFill = (s.Length - topup) >> pagedepth; // We want the floor here
            // fill up complete pages if necessary:
            if (remainingPagesToFill > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < remainingPagesToFill; i++)
                {
                    if (currentPage == c.Count) c.Add(new char[pagesize]);
                    for (int j = 0; j < pagesize; j++)
                    {
                        c[currentPage][j] = s[stringpos];
                        stringpos++;
                    }
                    currentPage++;
                }
            }
            // finish off remainder of string s on new page:
            if (currentPage == c.Count) c.Add(new char[pagesize]);
            for (int i = stringpos; i < s.Length; i++)
            {
                c[currentPage][currentPosInPage] = s[i];
                currentPosInPage++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what kind of crazy stuff one needs this large data-types for?

Comment: @t3chb0t: Converting giant CSV files for users of my software. Ask my users :)

Comment: ok... but isn't streaming it easier and faster than loading the entire file into memory? It screams: the [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Your users are not responsible for you wasting RAM :-P

Comment: The question you should be asking is how you can convert _this giant_ CSV more efficiently rather than brute-forcing it into your RAM.

Comment: @t3chb0t: In my dreams. The giant string will be analysed and manipulated more than once (e.g: checked for number of pairs of open/close braces, followed by special text replacements, then removing empty lines/whitespace, and other possible filtering, followed by consistency checks for column counts for every row). And that's just for one of the simpler conversions. These tasks will be slower if manipulation is performed repeatedly via HDD (or even SSD) instead of RAM.

Comment: oh boy... this sounds like you're pushing json over csv... this is even more scarry then I thought. This entire concept seems to be pretty odd :-| Why don't you do the filtering on the fly? Read, filter, write...? Anyway, have fun with this monster solution ;-]

Comment: @t3chb0t: Funnily enough, one of the possible conversions is from CSV to JSON, or vice versa :)

Comment: @DanW: it still sounds like treating the input as one giant string is not the most efficient approach. If you really can't process it in a streaming fashion, then did you look into specialized data structures such as ropes, gap buffers, piece tables, that sort of stuff?

Comment: @t3chb0t: There are many parts where the whole text needs to be loaded before it can even consider writing (consistency checks is one example, and so is obtaining all possible parameters to present to the user). Regardless, the giant 2D string array I also have (elegant mediator between input and output for many different file types) is about 3x larger in terms of memory. On the small off-chance loading/filtering line by line works, it'd be a complete rewrite of the code, which started off as a small project, but has grown beyond my initial expectations (to put it mildly).

Comment: @PieterWitvoet: See my comment above for more info. In answer to your question, no, though because the code is already very complex, I'd rather minimize further complexity in any way I can, especially if speed will end up being affected.

Comment: Is it not possible to parse the string in chunks and then deal with a >2GB list of objects than with a >2GB string? I think all you want to do (consistency checks, parameters, etc) will be easier to handle if you have your data in a data structure and not as text.

Comment: Regarding the solution itself, I would suggest you research `Span<T>` and friends. Since I don't know them well enough, I can't give a full answer with these.

Comment: You're talking about replacing and removing text. How do you plan to support those operations in an efficient manner? But you're also talking about a 2D string array. Why do you need to work with the input as a giant string(builder) if you already have a more appropriate data structure?

Comment: [This question is being discussed on meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9112/31562). In the mean-time I have rolled-back your edit where you replied to the answer below.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet: Just as one example, in case of a malformed CSV, some rows may have less/more columns than others, and I need to find the maximum number of columns for any row before creating the appropriately sized 2D array. Another thing which springs to mind is that I feel operating on millions of individual strings in a 2D string array would perform slower than in-place character replacements on a single giant BigStringBuilder. I could be mistaken though. Also to reiterate, there's no chance I'm rewriting the code at this stage - it'd be a lot of work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> ```
>     List<char[]> c = new List<char[]>();
>     private int pagedepth;
>     private long pagesize;
>     private long mpagesize;         // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040646/faster-modulus-in-c-c
>     private int currentPage = 0;
>     private int currentPosInPage = 0;
> ```

Some of these names are rather cryptic. I'm not sure why `c` isn't private. And surely some of the fields should be `readonly`?

---

> ```
>         pagesize = (long)Math.Pow(2, pagedepth);
> ```

IMO it's better style to use `1L << pagedepth`.

---

> ```
>     public char this[long n]    {
>         get { return c[(int)(n >> pagedepth)][n & mpagesize]; }
>         set { c[(int)(n >> pagedepth)][n & mpagesize] = value; }
>     }
> ```

Shouldn't this have bounds checks?

---

> ```
>     public string[] returnPagesForTestingPurposes() {
>         string[] s = new string[currentPage + 1];
>         for (int i = 0; i < currentPage + 1; i++) s[i] = new string(c[i]);
>         return s;
>     }
> ```

There's no need for this to be public: you can make it `internal` and give your unit test project access with `[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo]`. Also, since it's for testing purposes, it could probably be marked `[System.Diagnostics.Conditional("DEBUG")]`.

---

> ```
>     public void clear() {
>         c = new List<char[]>();
>         c.Add(new char[pagesize]);
> ```

In C# it's conventional for method names to start with an upper case letter.

There's no need to throw quite as much to the garbage collector. Consider as an alternative:

```
var page0 = c[0];
c.Clear();
c.Add(page0);
```

---

> ```
>     // See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373365/how-do-i-write-out-a-text-file-in-c-sharp-with-a-code-page-other-than-utf-8/373372
> ```

Why? I don't think it sheds any light on the following method.

> ```
>     public void fileSave(string path)   {
>         StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path);
>         for (int i = 0; i < currentPage; i++) sw.Write(new string(c[i]));
>         sw.Write(new string(c[currentPage], 0, currentPosInPage));
>         sw.Close();
>     }
> ```

Missing some [disposal](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable.dispose?view=netframework-4.7.2): I'd use a [`using` statement](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement).

`new string(char[])` copies the entire array to ensure that the string is immutable. That's completely unnecessary here: `StreamWriter` has a method `Write(char[], int, int)`.

---

> ```
>     public void fileOpen(string path)   {
>         clear();
> ```

Yikes! That should be mentioned in the method documentation.

> ```
>         StreamReader sw = new StreamReader(path);
>         int len = 0;
>         while ((len = sw.ReadBlock(c[currentPage], 0, (int)pagesize)) != 0){
>             if (!sw.EndOfStream)    {
>                 currentPage++;
>                 if (currentPage == c.Count) c.Add(new char[pagesize]);
>             }
>             else    {
>                 currentPosInPage = len;
>                 break;
> ```

I think this can give rise to inconsistencies. Other methods seem to assume that if the length of the `BigStringBuilder` is an exact multiple of `pagesize` then `currentPosInPage == 0` and `c[currentPage]` is empty, but this can give you `currentPosInPage == pagesize` and `c[currentPage]` is full.

This method is also missing disposal.

---

> ```
>     public long length()    {
>         return (long)currentPage * (long)pagesize + (long)currentPosInPage;
>     }
> ```

Why is this a method rather than a property? Why use multiplication rather than `<<`?

---

> ```
>     public string substring(long x, long y) {
>         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
>         for (long n = x; n < y; n++) sb.Append(c[(int)(n >> pagedepth)][n & mpagesize]);    //8s
> ```

What is `8s`? Why append one character at a time? `StringBuilder` also has a method which takes `(char[], int, int)`.

---

> ```
>     public bool match(string find, long start = 0)  {
>         //if (s.Length > length()) return false;
>         for (int i = 0; i < find.Length; i++) if (i + start == find.Length || this[start + i] != find[i]) return false;
>         return true;
>     }
> ```

What does this method do? The name implies something regexy, but there's no regex in sight. The implementation looks like `StartsWith` (by default - the offset complicates it).

---

> ```
>     public void replace(string s, long pos) {
>         for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)  {
>             c[(int)(pos >> pagedepth)][pos & mpagesize] = s[i];
>             pos++;
>         }
>     }
> ```

Bounds checks?

---

> ```
>     // This method is a more sophisticated version of the Append() function above.
>     // Surprisingly, in real-world testing, it doesn't seem to be any faster.
> ```

I'm not surprised. It's still copying character by character. It's almost certainly faster to use `string.CopyTo` (thanks to [Pieter Witvoet](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/51173/pieter-witvoet) for mentioning this method) or `ReadOnlySpan.CopyTo`.

Comment: Thanks! Added responses to my main post if you want to look.

Comment: Regarding the last point, there's also `string.CopyTo`.

Comment: c# class instance members are private by default, so `c` is private. But you're right that it is inconsistent to not explicitly declare it private like the other fields are. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/accessibility-levels

Comment: Thanks. I gave a more [detailed response](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/214917/6) to my Q, but it was rolled back, so I'll keep things terse here: "Shouldn't this have bounds checks?": Not if we want maximum speed? Re: StreamWriter, doesn't `Close()` dispose the StreamWriter when the method ends, like other normal class objects outside of scope would be? If not, I could use `sw=null;`? "I'm not surprised. It's still copying character by character.": I expected faster because there isn't the If condition (`if (currentPosInPage == pagesize)`) for every character that's appended.

Comment: @DanW, that's not what I meant by disposal. I've added a couple of links which should make it clearer.

Comment: Apparently, `StreamWriter.Close()` just calls `StreamWriter.Dispose()` [under the bonnet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1187727/848344), so maybe my `Close()` statement is sufficient?

Comment: @DanW: `using` translates to a `try/finally` statement that ensures disposal even when an exception is thrown, so it's almost always the better approach.

Comment: By the way, for your info, appending using `string.CopyTo` is around 3.2x as fast as my original code! Code is: `s.CopyTo(0, c[currentPage], currentPosInPage, s.Length); currentPosInPage += s.Length;`. Just for fun, I also tried: `Array.Copy(s.ToCharArray(), 0, c[currentPage], currentPosInPage, s.Length); currentPosInPage += s.Length;`, and that was not quite as good (2.1x faster), but still better than my original code.

Answer (score 4):

#### Design considerations

In the comments you mentioned that you're going to analyze and manipulate this string? If so, that could be a problem, because replacing, inserting and removing text requires moving all subsequent characters to make room or to fill the gap. With this much data, you can expect that to have a major impact on performance. That is why I mentioned data structures like ropes, gap buffers and piece tables: those are often used in text editors to efficiently support these kind of operations.

But I think that would be solving the wrong problem. From what I understand so far, the rest of your code is built around a 2D array of strings - a table, essentially - that can be converted to a variety of formats. Because it's an array, you need to know the number of columns and rows up-front, so you need to parse the input before you can allocate the array, and then parse it again to fill the array. This `BigStringBuilder` class allows you to read the whole file into memory, so you don't have to read it from disk twice.

Why not use dynamically resizable arrays (`List<T>`) instead? That would allow you to read the data directly into your final data structure with only a single parsing pass. If that requires a lot of work, then you're probably suffering from a lack of abstraction. Instead of passing a raw `string[,]` around, wrap it in a class. That allows you to swap the internal 2D array for a more suitable data structure without having to modify all the code that uses this table.

For example, a `List<List<string>>` as internal data structure lets you add variable-length rows on-the-fly, so you only need a single parsing pass. That also allows you to read the input file in a streaming fashion instead of having to read it fully into memory first.

If modifying existing code that relies in a 2D string array sounds like a lot of work, consider emulating the 'interface' of a 2D array. With a class that provides a `string this[int row, int column]` indexer and a `GetLength(int dimension)` method, chances are that you only need to change the type of a bunch of parameters and variables.

---

#### Other notes

- Putting `if` and `for` bodies on the same line makes control flow difficult to follow.
- `fileSave` and `fileOpen` are not very flexible. Letting the caller pass in a `Stream` or `TextReader`/`TextWriter` would make them more reusable. That also gives callers control over things like encoding and buffer size. Additionally, overloads like `CopyToStream(Stream toStream, long offset, long count)` and `CopyFromStream(Stream fromStream, long count)` are probably also a good idea.
- `c[(int)(n >> pagedepth)][n & mpagesize]` is duplicated several times in the code. Use `this[n]` instead.
- There's very little documentation, especially for infrastructure-level code like this. I don't know about you, but I tend to forget things about code I wrote a while ago, so documentation that explains why something works the way it does, or how something is intended to be used, is quite useful.
- I'd recommend using more self-descriptive names, and aiming for consistency with the standard types you're 'emulating':

  - `this[n]` -> `this[index]`
  - `substring(x, y)` -> `Substring(startIndex, length)`
  - `replace(s, pos)` -> `Overwrite(value, startIndex)` (I find `replace` confusing because it's so different from what `string.Replace` does)
- Regarding camelCase vs PascalCase, I don't see why it's important to distinguish between standard library code and your own, but to each their own I guess. But why the inconsistency in `ToString` and `Append`?
- I'd argue that correctness is more important than performance. Leaving out bounds checks should be a last resort, and only when profiling shows that they're actually a bottleneck. Chances are that it's possible to improve the API so you don't need to access individual characters so often.
- I agree with Peter that `fileOpen` clearing the string-builder is unexpected behavior, in a negative way.
  Certainly the caller can call `clear` before `fileOpen` if that's the behavior they want? Otherwise, I would clearly document this.
- `length` being a method is inconsistent with `StringBuilder` and other collection types. A little bit of calculation in a property should be fine.
- If you're using `returnPagesForTestingPurposes` for automated testing then you're testing implementation details, which is a bad idea. If you're using it for debugging, then why not inspect the data with a debugger instead, or use tracepoints?

Comment: I manipulate the string so that in-place replacements are either equal in length, or shorter, so that reading can continue whilst the same BigStringBuilder is being operated on. Your idea of using List<T> is interesting regardless. Honestly, a part of me would love to experiment and refactor the program like you say to compare speed, but time is limited. FYI, `string[,]` is poor only allowing for 2^28 elements in total. `string[][]` allows essentially around 2^56 elements, far better.

Comment: Quote: "c[(int)(n >> pagedepth)][n & mpagesize] is duplicated several times in the code": Sadly, I found function calling slower than writing the code direct, possibly due to the compiler not inlining it. Quote: "But why the inconsistency in ToString and Append?": I have less excuse with Append(), but ToString was due to overriding the default ToString method. Quote: "Leaving out bounds checks should be a last resort": Either way, it'll crash and I can easily solve the bug. Besides, the program has already been heavily tested, so safety is less of a concern now.

Comment: So you're using a jagged array then? In that case you could parse the input directly into a `List<string[]>` and convert it to a `string[][]` afterwards, so you don't need to modify any of the other code at all. About inlining, you could try marking the indexer's getter and setter with `MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining`. Note that `replace` can be optimized by using `string.CopyTo`. About bounds checks, if 'it'll crash' means that you're expecting it to throw an exception anyway, then that's not the case when accessing unused characters in the last page.

Comment: One other factor to consider is when the user changes settings after the results are displayed. Reading it all out from HDD into a 2D array, would next a second HDD read after the user adjusts a single setting afterwards as it would need to be reparsed. Regarding `AggressiveInlining`, it seems to do the trick, but requires .NET 4.5, and I fear many of my users are still using .NET 3.5/4. Pretty astonishing that the C# team haven't fixed the issue until .NET4.5+.